# Is it possible to have console/SSH-like communication between 2 RPis/RPi and Linux machine using RF transceivers?

Tags: networking, wifi, ssh, hardware, radio

I am currently working on a project where a Raspberry Pi will be used to run an nmap scan on a (purpose built) wireless network, and then attempt to exploit vulnerabilities found on the network.

The exploiting Raspberry Pi will be mounted on a drone, and often well outside the range of a WiFi network that might be used to remotely control the Raspberry Pi, but still with line of sight. Therefore, I need to send commands and receive back results, preferably in an SSH-like fashion, to the Raspberry Pi. I'm thinking I'd do this from another Raspberry Pi or some other Linux machine.

Due to range limitations, I'm thinking that an RF connection would be a decent solution. My question is, is it possible to have that kind of control via an RF transceiver connection, and if so, would such a connection need to be full duplex, or just half-duplex? If so, what hardware would work for this? I may already be using 868 MHz frequency (RFM95/LoRa) for controlling the drone.

Thanks for any and all help.

EDIT: The answer to the question was **yes**. We were able to use a pair of 433 MHz LoRa radios from Adafruit, 1 connected via GPIO/serial to each Pi, to get reasonably functional two-way communication. One Pi was the "ground station" sending commands, while the other Pi on the radio received the commands and sent back terminal output successfully.

Comment: *"what hardware would work for this?"* -> If you want to use IP based apps (eg. ssh), you need something that provides a network interface over USB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable the Pi's serial input via raspi-config and use the radio transceivers as a uart-radio-uart bridge.
If you use different channels for up- and down-link (so that the channels do not interfere), everything would be exactly like if you controlled the Pi via its serial command line. The software wouldn't even care about  how data is transmitted physically.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thank you!